# Replace "Shift-Enter" line break with "Enter" in word document using Microsoft office API

Tags: api, ms-word, ms-office, line-breaks

I have a number of word documents that will be converted to HTML. It is required the paragraphs in the word documents should be converted to `<p>` elements.

After some tests with the Microsoft Office API's SaveAs method to convert the documents to the HTML, I realized the paragraphs with manual line breaks (break by "Shift-Enter") couldn't be placed in a separated `<p>` element, instead the paragraphs are grouped in a same `<p>` element.

In order to separate them, I have been trying to replace the "Shift-Enter" line breaks with the "Enter"/Carriage return before doing the conversion. However, I couldn't find a suitable way to do the line break replacement job. I have tried the WdLineEndingType parameter  in the SaveAs method, but it seems not effective for the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ms-word office API provides a find function in the Range object, enabling to search and replace the strings.

The following code is to find the manual line breaks("^l") with the carriage return("^p").

```
Range r = oDoc.Content;
r.WholeStory();
r.Find.Execute("^l", ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, "^p", WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
```

Then use SaveAs to convert the word document to HTML, it will properly place each lines in `<p>` elements.

Answer (score 18):

For those looking in MS Word: use Control-H (Find & replace).

Find Special character: manual Line break (^l, lowercase L)
Replace with: Paragraph mark (^p)
Replace All will do the whole document.

**Edit**: changed  to lowercase characters.

Answer (score 0):

Paragraph mark ( Paragraph mark )

^p (doesn't work in the Find what box when the Use wildcards option is turned on), or ^13